# Altium PCB: what do these patterns on traces and vias mean?

Tags: pcb, altium

I was just checking a PCB design, and found these box-patterns on some of the nets. What do they mean?

[image]

Comment: I have never seen anything like that before. When you hover over it, what does the HUD show?

Comment: If you zoom enough on that pattern you might see some message/label written on it

Comment: No, I don't see anything except the net name

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It looks like its related to the default [Base Pattern](http://techdocs.altium.com/display/ADRR/PCB_Dlg-InsightColorOverrideFrame((PCB+Editor+-+Board+Insight+Color+Overrides))_AD) (Checker Board) for board insight color override.

[image]

> The assigned net color is displayed using small squares, leaving the default layer color also visible. (This is the default override pattern).

Related article: [Customizing of Net Colors](http://techdocs.altium.com/display/ADOH/Customization+of+Net+Colors#CustomizationofNetColors-OverridePatterns)

Answer (score 0):

Press F5 and the checkboard pattern goes away